# How to deal with a complex data aggregation issue in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with data on all cabinet ministers across the world from 1966 to 2021. In total, the dataset contains data on 56,063 cabinet members in 177 countries, adding up to 8,811 country-years. My goal is to calculate the number of times that each cabinet minister has been reshuffled over the course of their existence in the data.

I want to code a minister as having been reshuffled if he or she holds different cabinet positions in consecutive years, according to data collected annually in July (e.g., Minister of Defense in year $t$, Minister of Economy in year $t+1$, back to Minister of Defense in year $t+2$). Given the annual data collection interval, it is possible that an individual could have moved between multiple positions within the same year, a detail that would not be captured in my dataset. Therefore, while my approach accurately identifies reshuffles on a year-to-year basis, it may potentially underestimate the overall extent of cabinet reshuffles that occur within a single year.

There are some interesting features of my data that make doing this challenging. For example, an individual $i$ may serve in multiple positions $p$ in a given year (e.g., an individual might serve as both Ministry of Defense and then also as Minister of the Economy in another observation, in which case there would be two observations with the same person). I do not want to code as reshuffling situations where you keep a position from year to year, but then take on an additional ministry in a subsequent year. For example, an individual $i$ serves as Minister of Defense in year $t$, but then in year $t+1$ also serves as Minister of Education (while retaining his post as Minister of Defense). Only if you have one position and then get another does it count as a reshuffle. I also don't want to count observations where someone is classified as the de facto leader of a country (e.g. Prime Minister or President), in which case they cannot be reshuffled, but are the ones doing the reshuffling.

Here is my attempt to do all of this in `R`:

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

# Load data
data <- fread("individual_cabinet_autocracy.csv")

# Identify the duplicate column names
duplicate_column_names <- names(data)[duplicated(names(data))]

# Step 2: Rename or remove the duplicate columns
data <- data %>%
  rename_with(~ paste0(., "_renamed"), all_of(duplicate_column_names))

# Calculate reshuffles 
reshuffle_data <- data %>%
  filter(leader == 0) %>%  # Exclude leaders
  arrange(unique_id, year) %>%  # Arrange data by name and year
  group_by(unique_id) %>%        # Group data by individual names
  mutate(reshuffled = position != lag(position)) %>%  # Create a reshuffled indicator column
  summarize(reshuffle_count = sum(reshuffled, na.rm = TRUE))  # Sum reshuffles for each individual

# Arrange the summary data in descending order of total_movements
reshuffle_data <- reshuffle_data %>%
  arrange(desc(reshuffle_count))
```

This does not seem to be doing what I want. For example, it appears to be capturing individuals who stayed in the same position across consecutive years as reshuffles, but this is not the case. Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OBcfXtvJ_MMdxUpj1nXjKUzkWjj_wJpD/view?usp=sharing) to the full dataset.

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you (1) provide a reproducible example (incl. sample data, posted inline as a dataframe definition), (2) simplify the specific problem you're having trouble with - there's a lot of subject matter content/context here that makes it harder to understand what procedure you want to execute in code, (3) provide expected output vs output that your current code produces (formatted inline).  With a clear, well-scoped question and a reproducible example, you're likely to get help much faster.

Comment: What is `unique_id`, and how is it related to the `position` and country fields?

Comment: `unique_id` is the id of a minister in the dataset. Each minister has a unique id. Position is the position (cabinet ministry) a person occupies.

Comment: It will be easiest to help if you can edit your question to include one or more examples of data that demonstrate the issue, ideally reflecting any edge cases you want to address. It is most helpful if that data can be in code we can run, like `data.frame(position = c(....` or using the `dput` function to convert an object (or a subset in this case) to code that generates it.

Comment: Without example data in the question, my suggestion would be to look at the positions instead of the people, e.g. `data %>% arrange(year) %>% mutate(replacement = unique_id != lag(unique_id), .by = c(country, position))` and perhaps additional checks excluding where someone took over an empty/new role, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `leader` column is not accurate.
There are still “Prime Ministers”, and “Presidents” after filtering `leader == 0`.
Also, there are Ministers and other non-leader classifications flagged as leaders.
Your `core` and `minister` columns seem incorrect as well.

To detect the reshuffling you describe in your question,
it is best to include only `classification == "Minister (Full Rank)"`.
Below, I am showing steps to develop a solution that satisfies your specifications:

```r
# `readr::read_csv()` repairs column names so we don't have to worry about
# duplicate column names. Also, your data is moderately sized, and the use of
# `data.table::fread()` isn't warranted.
library(tidyverse)
data <- read_csv("individual_cabinet_autocracy.csv")

# Adding `unique_id`, selecting relevant columns, and filtering rows.
data2 <-
  data |>
  mutate(unique_id = cur_group_id(),
         .by = c(country_isocode, name)) |> 
  select(unique_id, name, year, position, classification) |>
  filter(classification == "Minister (Full Rank)") |>
  arrange(unique_id, year)

# Calculate reshuffles
reshuffle_data2 <-
  data2 |>
  group_by(unique_id, name) |>   
  mutate(reshuffled = position != lag(position)) |> 
  summarize(reshuffle_count = sum(reshuffled, na.rm = TRUE),
            .groups = "drop")
```

Using the code from your question, we get a reshuffle count of 2 for
“Osvaldo Dorticos Torrado”. Even though there is a
5 year gap between his 2nd and 3rd time as a Minister.
Let’s only count position changes that happen from year to year.

```r
reshuffle_data2 <-
  data2 |>
  group_by(unique_id, name) |>
  mutate(reshuffled = position != lag(position) &
           year - lag(year) == 1) |>
  summarize(reshuffle_count = sum(reshuffled, na.rm = TRUE),
            .groups = "drop")

reshuffle_data2 |> 
  arrange(desc(reshuffle_count))
#> # A tibble: 17,252 × 3
#>    unique_id name                reshuffle_count
#>        <int> <chr>                         <int>
#>  1     15906 Qaboos Said Said                 37
#>  2     11507 H. Kamuzu Banda                  23
#>  3     20544 Jayakumar Shunmugam              21
#>  4      8696 Joseph Mobutu                    17
#>  5     19030 Than Shwe                        17
#>  6      7705 Georges Rawiri                   16
#>  7     20522 Edward W. Barker                 16
#>  8      9750 Jackson Makweta                  13
#>  9     19157 R. Premadasa                     13
#> 10      5516 Toumany Sangare                  12
#> # ℹ 17,242 more rows
```

Now we get “Qaboos Said Said” as the most reshuffled person. By looking at the
data, we see that he has two minister positions simultaneously, and at some
point, a third one is added. According to your description, this should not be
counted as reshuffling. To classify a reshuffle, we’ll have to detect
if the previous position is lost when a new one is gained.

To do this, we are going to transform the data so that each row represents
the period a person has spent in a position.

```r
reshuffle_prep <-
  data2 |>
  group_by(unique_id, name, position) |>
  summarise(
    year_start = min(year),
    year_end = max(year),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) |>
  group_by(unique_id, name) |>
  arrange(unique_id, year_start) |>
  mutate(
    reshuffled = position != lag(position) &
      year_start - lag(year_end) == 1 & lag(year_end) < year_start
  )

reshuffle_prep |>
  count(unique_id, name, reshuffled, sort = TRUE) |>
  filter(reshuffled)
#> # A tibble: 4,530 × 4
#> # Groups:   unique_id, name [4,530]
#>    unique_id name                   reshuffled     n
#>        <int> <chr>                  <lgl>      <int>
#>  1      5516 Toumany Sangare        TRUE          12
#>  2      7705 Georges Rawiri         TRUE          11
#>  3      5512 NFamara Keita          TRUE          10
#>  4      7691 Jean-Stanislas Migolet TRUE          10
#>  5      9750 Jackson Makweta        TRUE          10
#>  6      5511 Damantang Camara       TRUE           9
#>  7      9360 Ruhakana Rugunda       TRUE           9
#>  8      5502 Moussa Diakite         TRUE           8
#>  9      8577 Pierre Moussa          TRUE           8
#> 10      9553 Jeremiah Nyagah        TRUE           8
#> # ℹ 4,520 more rows
```

Now “Toumany Sangare” seems to be the most reshuffled person.
Looking at the data, it seems that some of the detected shuffling might be
due to inconsistencies in the position naming (“Min. Of People’s Army” vs.
“Min. Of The People’s Army”). If this is an issue you should look into
harmonizing the position names, but I think it is out-of-scope for this question.